# Using userEvent to simulate keydown on Document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

Is it possible to achive this `fireEvent.keyDown(document, { key: '/' });` with `userEvent`?

This test passes:

```
test('is visible after pressing `/`', () => {
  render( < App / > );

  fireEvent.keyDown(document, {
    key: '/'
  });

  const input = screen.getByRole('textbox');

  expect(input).toBeVisible();
});
```

But when I try to do the same with userEvent:

```
test('is visible after pressing `/`', () => {
  render( < App / > );

  // Note: I'm not using `userEvent.type` because you can't type on `document`. Also, using `await` doesn't make the test pass.
  userEvent.keyboard('/')

  const input = screen.getByRole('textbox');

  expect(input).toBeVisible();
});
```

The test fails.

Comment: How is your event listener set up?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Like this: https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/yLqjoor?editors=0010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` has a special meaning with keyboard: to release a held key.

Try escaping it: `userEvent.keyboard('\/')`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried `userEvent.keyboard('\/')` and `await userEvent.keyboard('\/')`. The test still fails.

Comment: I'm confused--the test fails but the answer was accepted? What was the fix or did this work after all?